# PropertyChanged in binding

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I don't understand how the `PropertyChanged` event works in a binding context.
Please consider this simple code:

```
public class ImageClass
{
    public Uri ImageUri { get; private set; }
    public int ImageHeight { get; set; }
    public int ImageWidth { get; set; }
    public ImageClass(string location)
    {
        //
    }        
}

public ObservableCollection<ImageClass> Images
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<ImageClass>)GetValue(ImagesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImagesProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ImagesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Images", typeof(ObservableCollection<ImageClass>), typeof(ControlThumbnail), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

at run-time I make changes to some element of the `Images` Collection:

```
Images[i].ImageWidth = 100;
```

It has no effect - as far as I understand because the `PropertyChanged` event is not defined and then not fired.

I'm a confused how to declare such an event and what I need to put inside the event handler function.

I tried to do this:

```
foreach (object item in Images)
{
    if (item is INotifyPropertyChanged)
    {
        INotifyPropertyChanged observable = (INotifyPropertyChanged)item;
        observable.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(ItemPropertyChanged);
    }
}

private void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: its an event you have to fire after you set the value of the object(After the setters Setvalue), and on your view you would set the {Binding YourObject, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}...this way the view will know the property changed its value and would ask the getter for the new value :)

Comment: @BernardWalters Please note that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has nothing to with a binding source that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and fires a PropertyChanged event. Actually, `UpdateSourceTrigger` controls how a TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding triggers an update of the source object when the target object has changed, which never happens in a OneWay Binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `ImageClass` like this:

```
public class ImageClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int imageWidth;
    public int ImageWidth
    {
        get { return imageWidth; }
        set
        {
            imageWidth = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ImageWidth)));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the syntax of the Invoke statement?  I hadn't seen this flavor before.

Comment: That's the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx). It saves you a null check on the event.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I was able to extend to all other properties. Just a clarification: when I would need to set `{Binding YourObject, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}` in the view, as per Bernard comment?

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has nothing to with INotifyPropertyChanged. See my comment on your question. The only place where you may ever need to set it is in a binding of the Text property of a TextBox, when you want the binding source to be updated on every key stroke in the TextBox.